# Sublime text: Merge multiple adjacent white spaces into one

Tags: text, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How to do this in sublime text

```
"aaa     bbb ccc    ddddddd   "
```

should get converted to

```
"aaa bbb ccc ddddddd "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
${SELECTION/\s{2,}/ /g}
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

Then create a keybinding to call that snippet in your `Preferences -> KeyBindings - User` file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+z"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/Snippets/test_snippets/regex_whitespace.sublime-snippet" } },
```

Then, select text on a line, or multiple lines, and use the keymap.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done with a regex search and replace. First, select the text you want to alter. Next, click on **`Find -> Replace...`**. Make sure the <kbd>Regex</kbd> and <kbd>In selection</kbd> buttons are selected. To visualize what you're going to replace, you can also select the <kbd>Highlight matches</kbd> button as well. In the `Find What` field, enter `(\s){2,}`, and in the `Replace With` field, just enter a space. Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>, and all instances of two or more whitespace characters will be replaced with a single space.